# While loop produce incorrect results with no breakpoints in C# program

Tags: c#

I am having  weird problem with the code below where when I exclude breakpoints from my while loop,  the results are different.

The foreach loop, loops through 20 items from a list and adds each item to a dictionary.

When I add a breakpoint in the loop and skip through 20 times,  20 items are added.

If I remove all breakpoints and run the program only 1 item is added.

```
public void AddLinks(Dictionary<Guid,string> RowKeyTitles)
{
    var combinedUrlsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var urlTemplate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["playlisturl"];
    var count = 0;

    foreach (var row in RowKeyTitles)
    {
        var shortUrl = StringGenerator.GenerateShortLink(4);
        var combinedUrl = urlTemplate.Replace("{name}", row.Value).Replace("{id}",row.Key.ToString());

        while (!combinedUrlsList.ContainsKey(shortUrl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");

            shortUrl = StringGenerator.GenerateShortLink(4);

            if (!combinedUrlsList.ContainsKey(shortUrl))
            {
                count++; 
                Console.WriteLine("Added{0}", count);
                combinedUrlsList.Add(shortUrl, combinedUrl);

            }
        }              
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Count{0}",combinedUrlsList.Count());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Does anyone knows what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: The only way breakpoints are having any impact is if you are using data that is not fully loaded before running this function. You may be allowing the data to fill on a different thread while you are waiting on the break point. There is no way the code is actually doing something different because of the break point. Somewhere that has to be something to do with your timing.

Comment: What does StringGenerator.GenerateShortLink(4) do?

Answer (score 2):

I will make a guess and say that `StringGenerator.GenerateShortLink(4);` generates the same `shortUrl` in a tight loop. This is most probably, you are creating a new `Random` class in the loop.

An example for broken code

```
while(.....)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    rnd.Next();
}
```

This would generate many `same` numbers, since `Random()` uses system time as a seed.

To fix. declare `Random` as a your class's private field and create it only once.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation with the information given is that `StringGenerator.GenerateShortLink` is implemented in a way that it is "timinig-sensitive" - for example if it uses a `Random` instance internally and recreates it at every call... in such a case the newly created instance (by default) is initialized utilizing the current system time... with breakpoints it gets delayed enough that it produces a different random number... without breakpoints it gets initialized with the same number (because there is not enough delay) and thus produces the same random number(s) which in turn produces the same `shortUrl` it already produced the first time... since that is already part of the Dictionary `combinedUrlsList` it just won't be added a second time...

Fix for the above behaviour:
Don't recreate the `Random` instance used inside `StringGenerator.GenerateShortLink` between calls but reuse the already created instance in subsequent calls...